# JPA, update object in list

Tags: jpa

i have an ArrayList of offers ,but the problem is if an item in my ArrayList gets updated , it always becomes the last item of my list .

**Exemple:** i have a list of offers, i go to the database, i change the name of the first offer , when i display the list with getOffers , i will see that the item i updated moved from first position to last position .

Comment: Could you give us some code? example of change? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Selecting data from database

If you ever do select something from database without any sorting nor ordering you cannot be sure about sequence in which you retrive data.

More info [HERE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053)

Best way would be to put some Order By in your query.

### OneToMany/ ManyToMany ordering

If you get your data from any JPA relations like **@OneToMany** or **@ManyToMany** where your collection is mapped from some column, without ordering you cannot be sure to keep always the same order. You will get any order your database engine will give you. Same idea as in previous point.

To order data in this case, you can sort it or (which I prefer) order it with annotation **@OrderBy** or **@OrderColumn**.

On difference between Sorting and Ordering [LINK](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/ordering-vs-sorting-hibernate-use/)

Comment: thank you !
a question , does the 'action' of the commandbutton of primefaces work without the 'update' attribute ?
because it seems to not work for me without update

Comment: I've never been a master of PrimeFaces but try work with ajax parameter. I am here for JPA : )

Comment: also if i use h:commandbutton, everytime i do refresh my page, the growl shows me all the messages

Comment: Sorry not an expert of that matter, hope i helped with JPA : )